# Bitwise operator "OR" in this code (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

I have a question on how this operator works here:

```
var x = 808 / 60 | 0; // Will return 13
var y = 808 / 60; // Will return 13.466666666666667
```

Why adding a bitwise OR operator ( | ) here return me a integer?

Comment: because it casts 64 bit float to 32 bit int for the bitwise operation (and then back).

Comment: I'm reading the other threads, ty